# Optimize a query which computes Jackard similarity between two nodes from huge data sets

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have billions of nodes labelled Profile (:Profile {member_id, name, gender}) from which I need to compute Jaccard index between them & create a similarity relationship and assign the index as property.
There are Contact relationship between Male profile node to Female profile node and vice versa.

**Below is the CQL :**

Indexed gender.

```
MATCH (u1:Profile {gender:"Male"}), (u2:Profile {gender:"Male"}) WHERE u1 <> u2
MATCH (u1)-[:CONTACTED]->(u3:Profile {gender:"Female"})<-[:CONTACTED]-(u2) WITH u1, u2, count(u3.member) as intersect
MATCH (u1)-[:CONTACTED]->(u1_f:Profile {gender:"Female"}) WITH u1, u2, intersect, collect(DISTINCT u1_f.member) AS coll1
MATCH (u2)-[:CONTACTED]->(u2_f:Profile {gender:"Female"}) WITH u1, u2, collect(DISTINCT u2_f.member) AS coll2, coll1, intersect
WITH u1, u2, intersect, coll1, coll2, length(coll1 + filter(x IN coll2 WHERE NOT x IN coll1)) as union
Where (1.0*intersect/union) > 0
CREATE Unique (u1)-[:SIMILARITY {score: (1.0*intersect/union)}]-(u2);
```

If I execute this with a limit of 5 it takes approx 5mins to yield the results which is not feasible at all. **What can I do to speed up the execution time as this is an important part of my project?**

I thought something like below would work but it made it worse.

Created a constraint on member.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:{path_to_csv}/member_to_member.csv" AS row
MATCH (u1:Profile {member: row.sentby}), (u2:Profile {gender:"Male"}) WHERE u1 <> u2 AND row.status = "Contacted" AND row.sentbygender = "Male"
MATCH (u1)-[:CONTACTED]->(u3:Profile {member: row.recdby})<-[:CONTACTED]-(u2) WITH row, u1, u2, count(u3.member) as intersect
//WHERE intersect>0
MATCH (u1)-[:CONTACTED]->(u1_f:Profile {member: row.recdby}) WITH row, u1, u2, intersect, collect(DISTINCT u1_f.member) AS coll1
MATCH (u2)-[:CONTACTED]->(u2_f:Profile {member: row.recdby}) WITH row, u1, u2, collect(DISTINCT u2_f.member) AS coll2, coll1, intersect
WITH u1, u2, intersect, coll1, coll2, length(coll1 + filter(x IN coll2 WHERE NOT x IN coll1)) as union
return u1.member, u2.member, (1.0*intersect/union) as score limit 5;
```

*member_to_member.csv*

```
sentby,sentbygender,recdby,recdbygender,date_of_contact,status
OSH34878034,Male,angella,Female,2013-11-12,Contacted
OSH34878034,Male,AnshuSharma,Female,2013-11-12,Contacted
OSH34878034,Male,GSH26933499,Female,2013-11-12,Contacted
OSH34878034,Male,4SH00112696,Female,2013-11-12,Contacted
OSH34878034,Male,0308heinz,Female,2013-11-12,Contacted
OSH34878034,Male,8SH93301323,Female,2013-11-12,Contacted
OSH34878034,Male,098w,Female,2013-11-12,Contacted
```

Source : 
http://www.lyonwj.com/twizzard-a-tweet-recommender-system-using-neo4j/

Note: Above query is only to find Male -> Male similarity

Thanks

Comment: Which Neo4j version are you using? Can you try it on 2.2 with profiling and share the profile results?

Comment: Do you have a sample database set up somewhere?

Comment: I'm using Neo4j enterprise 2.1.7. 
I can share the development CSVs with you.

Answer (score 3):

Use Java instead of Cypher.

Your first line already creates 1bn squared rows.

I'd probably create one big long array for all the profiles

I'd fold the 3 counters into one long (bitmask)

Then go over all the CONTACTED relationships for females (I would also promote the Gender to a Label)

And for each rel find the appropriate end-node entry by node-id index and increment the one of the 3 counters.

That should give you an array with the raw numbers and you can compute the results over that.

Comment: The requirement has changed, I no longer have to calculate the similarity between each profile but I'll surely try out your suggestion and post back soon.
Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The above query performs well with Neo4j 2.2.0.